# I am searching from a database. In the results It brings 3 rooms for a single hotel. This is displayed as 3 hotels in my android recyclerview

Tags: php, android

How do i filter an array list in php to skip one row that has already been added where one of its column value is repited.

I have tried using in_array to filter and array_exist

```
$getRoom = mysqli_query($con, $sql);      
    $json_array = array();     
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getRoom))  {    
        if (in_array($row['hotel_name'], $json_array)) {

        }     
         else { 
                 $json_array = $row;   
                    }     
}and 
 echo json_encode($json_array);
```

I want hotel name and one of the rooms found

Answer (score 0):

The code (as it is provided right now) is not actually adding a line to `$json_array`, it's just replacing the current value with the current row. `$json_array = $row;` needs to become `$json_array = $row[];`

The second issue is that in_array isn't going to recursively search the second level of array so it's never going to find `$row['hotel_name']`. I would recommend restructuring your arrays a bit (depending on how your downstream code is going to use them) to something more like this:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($getRoom))  {    
    $json_array[$row['hotel_name']][] = $row;
}
```

This will group your data so that each hotel is only listed once in the top level array but you keep all of the details about the various rooms. If you really only need the distinct hotel names then you should restructure your database query to only return unique values using a `distinct` clause.